# What happens when creaing crd without relating operator?

Tags: kubernetes

1. Once I register the crd into the k8s cluster, I can use .yaml to create it, without operator running. Then What happends to these created resouces?
2. I have seen the `Reconciler` of operator, but it's more like an async status transfer. When we create a pod, we can directly get the pod ip from the create result. But it seems that I didn't find a place to write my `OnCreate` hook. (I just see some `validate` webhook, but never see a hook that be called when creation request made, defines how to create the resourse, and return the created resourse info to the caller ).
3. If my story is that for one kind of resource, in a time window, all coming creation will multiplex only one pod. Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a big story for kubernetes `crd`/`controller` life cycle, I try to make a simple representation.

1. After register a new CRD, and create CR, `kube-api-server` do not care if there is a related `controller` existed or not. see the process:
   [image]

That's means the resource(your CR) will be store to etcd, has no business of your `controller`

2. ok, let talk about your controller. your controller will setup a `list/watch`(actually a long live http link) to the `api-server` and register  `hook`(what you ask, right?) for different event: `onCreate`, `onUpdate` and `onDelete`. Actually you will handle all event in your controller's `reconcile` (remember kubernetes reconcile's responsibility: move current state to desired state). see the diagram:
   [image]

3. For the `list/watch` link in your `controller`, you need set different link for different kind of resource. for example: if you care about event for `pod`, you need set `pod` `list/watch` or care about deployment, and set a `deployment` `list/watch`...

Comment: Thanks, learned a lot. I still have a question, when will the `reconcile` be called? If it's a callback, how can we do our routines when there is nothing changed? For example, we want to implement a cronjob, then in my views, the `reconcile` should be called periodly defined by the cron expression.

Comment: The routine things(like cronjob) should not adopt the `controller`/`reconcile`, the `controller`/`reconcile` is event driven, if nothing happen, it should do nothing.  You can leverage specific resource in kubernetes, like `cronjob`. another solution is little hard code, you can let the resource re-enqueue(and set the next dequeue time, for example, 10 minutes later) after first `reconcile`. then you get a routines thing...